# Django: bulk_destroy returns "400: Bad request"

Tags: django

I have a Django viewset `MyModelViewset` that extends `MultipleDBModelViewSet` (part of a third-party project called [`django-rest-framework-bulk`](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk)):

```
class MultipleDBModelViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            multiple_ids = json.loads(self.request.query_params.get("ids"))
        except (TypeError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
            multiple_ids = None
        if not multiple_ids:
            return self.get_serializer_class().Meta.model.objects.all()
        else:
            return self.get_serializer_class().Meta.model.objects.filter(pk__in=multiple_ids)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
    def destroy(self, request, *args, pk=None, **kwargs):
        return super().destroy(request, *args, pk=pk, **kwargs)

    def bulk_destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = json.loads(request.query_params.get("ids"))
        if not ids:
            return super().destroy(request, *args, pk=kwargs.pop("pk"), **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().bulk_destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The base viewset contains the following method that is not overwritten in `MyModelViewset`:

```
def bulk_destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ids = json.loads(request.query_params.get("ids"))
    if not ids:
        return super().destroy(request, *args, pk=kwargs.pop("pk"), **kwargs)
    else:
        return super().bulk_destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am assuming that this method means I can pass a parameter called `ids` and all of the objects with those `ids` will be deleted?

I've tried sending a delete request to the associated URL:

`v1/mymodel?ids=["4cea187e-56af-439c-96a7-e001d85c5000","3d7bd2ac-bc27-4a1b-acfd-9b651852114e"]`
-> this returns a 200 response and behaves like a `GET` request

`v1/mymodel?ids=["4cea187e-56af-439c-96a7-e001d85c5000","3d7bd2ac-bc27-4a1b-acfd-9b651852114e"]/`
-> this returns a 400 response "Bad request"

MyModels with these `ids` **do** exist in my DB, and I **can** delete individual MyModels with: `}/v1/mymodel/4cea187e-56af-439c-96a7-e001d85c5000`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does this `MultipleDBModelViewSet` come from? And also the `bulk_destroy`. It'd be nice if you could post them here but

Comment: This is a project that has been ongoing and I just hopped on (and discovered Django at the same time), it's in `base/viewset.py` and I assumed it was a built-in Django feature, I'll post the code here though

Comment: That's not part of Django and neither DjangoRestFramework. That's is part of a third-party project called `django-rest-framework-bulk` and I believe you can see more info here about this method you're looking for https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/rest_framework_bulk/drf3/mixins.py